# What's the parenthesized number next to "featured" in the mobile version of a tag's page?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, bountied-tab

[image: Mobile site, tag page, featured tab]

Question: **What does that number in the screenshot mean?**

---

To see this,

- Go to *the Featured tab of any tag's page* on Stack Overflow (such as [branch-prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch-prediction?sort=featured), [google-glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-glass?sort=featured), or [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=featured)),
- If you're on the full site, go to the *mobile site* (click the "mobile" link on the footer of the page, between "advertising info" and "contact us")
- As you can see, in the *order by* dropdown on the right, there's a number next to "featured", in parenthesis (e.g. featured **(36)**).

The funny thing is, if I refresh the page, the number seems to change randomly.
It doesn't seem related to anything.

---

Seen on:

- Chrome 31.0.1650.18 (on iOS 7.0.4)
- Safari (on iOS 7.0.4)
- Opera 12.16 (on Mac OS 10.9)
- Chrome 31.0.1650.63 (on Mac OS 10.9)