# The number next to the featured tab is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, sorting, homepage

On mobile (can't check main, but I suspect this bug isn't there on main), on a tag search page, the number next to the featured tab seems to be behaving strangely.

The [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) tag has 4 featured (bountied) questions.

[When I sort by frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel?sort=frequent) the featured tab(dropdown) has a "(409)" next to it.

[When I sort by newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel?sort=newest) it is 22

[When I sort by  featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel?sort=featured), it is 11.

Screenshot:

> [image]

None of these are the actual number, 5.

Comment: Always 409 for me. Going to add screenshot...

Comment: It's changing seemingly randomly for me, but I need to change to the featured tab for it to change. If I go from non-featured to another non-featured, it doesn't change, but if I go from featured to non-featured, it does. Anyway, it isn't the correct value. It showed 5 from all tabs until I clicked on featured (5) for the first time.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211191/212780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number had been disabled by localization. I've put it in again. Note that this is the same value as the desktop site, so you should see a similar behavior. Except caching.

Out in rev `2253` (here) and rev `1611` (network).